# how to change recyclerview item's layout from outside?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView, which has a Button and an EditText.
I have a Button outside of the RecyclerView. On click the outside Button, I want the Button in the RecyclerView toggles between hide and show.
How to do that?

I have tried to send a boolean parameter mEditFlag to the recyclerAdapter, toogle mEditFlag, and notify the adapter the data has changed. but it doesn't work.

```
mCurrentOrderRecyclerAdapter = new CurrentOrderRecyclerAdapter(this, mEditFlag);
    rvOrder.setAdapter(mCurrentOrderRecyclerAdapter);

rlEditOrderList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mEditFlag = !mEditFlag;
            mCurrentOrderRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (mEditFlag) {
                ivEditOrderList.setImageResource(R.drawable.order_edit_true);
                tvEditOrderList.setText(R.string.order_edit_flag_true);
            } else {
                ivEditOrderList.setImageResource(R.drawable.order_edit_false);
                tvEditOrderList.setText(R.string.order_edit_flag_false);
            }
        }
    });

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OrderRecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if(editFlag) {
        holder.rlLeftItemRvOrder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.rlLeftItemRvOrder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.tvNumItemRvOrder.setText(position + "x");
    holder.tvDesItemRvOrder.setText("holder.ivFoodItemRvOrder.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawer_menu)");
    holder.ivFoodItemRvOrder.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawer_menu);

}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 7):

You have to achieve it with your adapter layer.

The `Button` outside the `RecyclerView` **has to update the item inside** the adapter (for example a boolean).
Then notify the change to update (for example with the [notifyItemChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) method) the `RecyclerView`

Somenthing like:

```
rlEditOrderList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Update the item inside the adapter
            MyObject obj = mAdapter.getItem(position);
            obj.myBoolean= true;
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });
```

with an adapter like:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<MyObject> mDataset;

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            //Get the item in the adapter
            MyObject obj = getItem(position);
            if(obj.myBoolean)
               holder.mButtonView.setVisibile(View.VISIBLE);
            else
               holder.mButtonView.setVisibile(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm. What I do is set the mEditFlag inside the adapter to be public, change it outside of the adapter, and notify the adapter to update. Code is:     public boolean mEditFlag = false;
mCurrentOrderRecyclerAdapter.mEditFlag = mEditFlag;
mCurrentOrderRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();